# facebook parser which does not use facebook api

Tags: facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api

Do you know existing facebook parser which does not use facebook api? I'm asking because i would like to download photos of all of my friends and me but facebook blocks application api keys which do that (i created app in python for my private purpose only which does that and uses fb api and now facebook does not want to reply valid key). Using parser which fakes user agent and does not use api would be much less transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing the HTML which Facebook generates using something like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) (there are ports to many languages, likely also for the one you are using). But I'd like to state that the real problem here is possibly not a technical one, but rather a political one (but I'm not familiar enough with the FB API to be sure about that):

Facebook does not *want* to you to grab that stuff from their servers, and it's likely they will have some success enforcing that. For example they might throw in some captchas every now and then to stop your crawler. Or block access from your IP. Or whatnot. You'll be climbing some kind of escalation ladder when you start doing this.

Comment: Yeah but i don't think facebook will notice me if i don't make this public - so it will be only for bunch of photos (well, all of my friends it would thousands of photos but it should be still okay for them).

Comment: Then I'd use the scraping approach and hope FB doesn't notice/mind that.